# EditText's SetText method and TextChangedListener

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to determine the behavior between an EditText and TextChangedListener. I so far haven't really been able to understand, and I can't determine if using the SetText() method on the EditText fires methods inside of the TextChangedListener, such as the afterTextchanged method.

Are TextChangedListener events fired when a user inputs characters into an EditText, or is it also triggered when SetText() is called.

Comment: As far as I know, it only fires when a user actually enters text. You can easily test this by adding a listener and logging to the console.

Answer (score 1):

As Melllvar stated, you can easily test this theory yourself by Referencing a `TextView` and adding `TextChangedListener`. For example:

```
TextView tV = new TextView(this); // Or reference one.
tV.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "BeforeTextChanged", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "OnTextChanged", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "AfterTextChanged", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

All methods do indeed fire when calling `tV.setText("this is a test");`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok myabe my problem is elsewhere in the way I am set up, as it doesn't seem to fire when the setText is called for my EditText. I'll keep testing it. Thanks.

Comment: I'd be happy to analyze your code, if you post it :)  Post where you reference the TextView in your activity, and the xml that contains the textview.